# Getting -12v from motorcycle Indicator connection

Tags: voltage, electricity, indicator

Problem Solved, it was a silly mistake, I confused the battery positive with negative.

I am making a circuit where I need input from Indicator signals . But the connection plugs for both the Indicators are giving -12V reading with respect to the negative probe of bikes battery. Any idea why??? 
Help me out guys.

Comment: you have your meter leads connected the wrong way around? The bike is a positive ground?

Comment: Meter leads are right, I checked many times, bike is negative ground.

Answer (score 1):

There are some cars (and I presume motorcycles) where the + of the battery is connected to the chassis and uses that as a reference. However, that is quite rare and people even 'convert' such vehicles to the standard where - is connected to the chassis. So check which pole is connected to the chassis.

What is more likely is that you swapped + and - on your meter somehow.

Comment: I never saw  + connected to chassis, chassis always connected to GND.

Comment: It is rare to have a positive ground vehicle.  Rare enough that most people will have never seen it.

Comment: Positive earth is common on british classic cars .The cars were in the era of generators that were before alternators .